# Unity3D problem convert view input from PC to mobile

Tags: unity

I have the FPS game project that works great for PC with a new input system, but I want to convert all of the new input that I've created to work on mobile too, so I make more binding and attach it at the `OnScreenStick` and  `OnscreenButton` it works but except for `view` actions, the free look originally from `Delta[Mouse]` [image]

[image]

the `view is Vector2 control type`.

so I added a new binding to `view` actions Delta[TouchScreen] for mobile input, it works with `OnScreensStick` but it's slower than a mouse view.

[image]

[image]

this is my script looks like :

```cs
private Default_Input defaultInput;

private Vector3 newCameraRotation;
private Vector3 newPlayerRotation;

public CharacterSettingModel playerSettings;

public Transform camHolder;
public Vector2 input_View;

private void Awake()
{
        defaultInput = new Default_Input();
        defaultInput.Character.View.performed += e => input_View = e.ReadValue<Vector2>();

        defaultInput.Enable();

        newCameraRotation = camHolder.localRotation.eulerAngles;
        newPlayerRotation = transform.localRotation.eulerAngles;
}

private void CalculateView()
{
        newCameraRotation.y += playerSettings.ViewXSentivity * (playerSettings.ViewXInverted ? -input_View.x : input_View.x) * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(newPlayerRotation);

        newCameraRotation.x += playerSettings.ViewYSentivity * (playerSettings.ViewYInverted ? input_View.y : -input_View.y) * Time.deltaTime;
        newCameraRotation.x = Mathf.Clamp(newCameraRotation.x, viewClampYmin, viewClampYmax);

        camHolder.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(newCameraRotation);
}
```

I wonder why it can happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different input devices for the same action can provide a different "feel", which is often undesired but inherent in that not all input devices are created equal. But you can adjust for that by adding [processors](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/Processors.html#processors-on-bindings) to individual binding in your input actions asset. When one input method feels "slower" than another, then the "Scale" processor might be able to fix that.

Note that processors can be assigned on three different levels: The action, the binding and the control. Think carefully about where you want to add it to avoid unintended side-effects.

Comment: Hoo okay, thanks for the explanation